# Android studio takes 5x time to run a single buildTypes when multiple buildTypes are created in the project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, build.gradle

As the normal convention we were using the 2 `buildTypes` in our code, i.e. `release` & `debug` and everything works smoothly without any issue:

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config

            buildConfigField 'String', 'LibVersion', '"8.0.5"'

        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            def buildTime = new GregorianCalendar().format("MM-dd-yyyy' 'h:mm:ss a z")
            def gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${buildTime}\""
            buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"${gitSha}\""
            tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
                if (task.name.equals("lint")) {
                    task.enabled = false
                }
            }

            buildConfigField 'String', 'LibVersion', '"8.0.5"'
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
```

We've numerous ( for eg. >200) `productFlavors` in our app as part of our customers having the same code base but with their brandings.
We've multiple web environment (Multiple API Base URL) on which we used to develop our app, now requirements comes out to create any `productFlavors` with any environment. So for that we've created different `buildTypes` w.r.t to each environment. As creating other `productFlavors` w.r.t to each environment cost much more maintenance, for eg. if we've 10 web environment then we need to define 200*10 `productFlavors`.

Code after changes:

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config

            buildConfigField 'String', 'MY_WEB_URL', '"https://URL1/"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LibVersion', '"8.0.5"'

        }
        releaseEnv2 {
            initWith(buildTypes.release)
            buildConfigField 'String', 'MY_WEB_URL', '"https://URL2/"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LibVersion', '"8.0.1"'
        }
        releaseEnv3 {
            initWith(buildTypes.release)
            buildConfigField 'String', 'MY_WEB_URL', '"https://URL3/"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LibVersion', '"8.0.1"'
        }
        releaseEnv4 {
            initWith(buildTypes.release)
            buildConfigField 'String', 'MY_WEB_URL', '"https://URL4/"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LibVersion', '"8.0.1"'
        }
        releaseEnv5 {
            initWith(buildTypes.release)
            buildConfigField 'String', 'MY_WEB_URL', '"https://URL5/"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LibVersion', '"8.0.1"'
        }
        releaseEnv6 {
            initWith(buildTypes.release)
            buildConfigField 'String', 'MY_WEB_URL', '"https://URL6/"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LibVersion', '"8.0.1"'
        }
        releaseEnv7 {
            initWith(buildTypes.release)
            buildConfigField 'String', 'MY_WEB_URL', '"https://URL7/"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LibVersion', '"8.0.1"'
        }
        releaseEnv8 {
            initWith(buildTypes.release)
            buildConfigField 'String', 'MY_WEB_URL', '"https://URL8/"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LibVersion', '"8.0.1"'
        }
        releaseEnv9 {
            initWith(buildTypes.release)
            buildConfigField 'String', 'MY_WEB_URL', '"https://URL9/"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LibVersion', '"8.0.1"'
        }
        releaseReplicaDebug {
            initWith(buildTypes.release)
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            def buildTime = new GregorianCalendar().format("MM-dd-yyyy' 'h:mm:ss a z")
            def gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${buildTime}\""
            buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"${gitSha}\""
            tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
                if (task.name.equals("lint")) {
                    task.enabled = false
                }
            }

            buildConfigField 'String', 'MY_WEB_URL', '"https://URL_DEBUG/"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LibVersion', '"8.0.5"'

            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
```

Now with multiple `buildTypes` Android studio is taking more than 5x time while running any `productFlavors`.

Please help me here if anybody has any clue for the same.

Thanks in advance!

I've tried with multiple solutions like playing around with `gradle.properties` file for memory allocation changes in `org.gradle.jvmargs`, code inspection etc.

I'm expecting the same build run time with multiple `buildTypes` or a different solution to cover the different web environment requirements.

Comment: Does the increase in build time also occur in local builds or only in Azure DevOps?

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT it got increased on both